# presentModalViewController iPhone

Tags: iphone, view, controller, modal-dialog

I am working with iPhone app. I have to jump to the ProfileViewController(from HomeViewController) by following code:

```
ProfileViewController *ProfilePage = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
ProfilePage.RequestType = 2;
ProfilePage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

UINavigationController *navigationControllerNew = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ProfilePage];

//Present navigationController as Model viw controller  
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationControllerNew animated:YES];

//release it After presenting to it
[navigationControllerNew release];
[ProfilePage release];
```

Its working fine, but When I come back to same page after clicking on ProfileViewController's "Last view" button, it comes back again but after coming back. My `popToViewController` on back button doesn't work on HomeScreenController. Might be Because of new Navigation controller in the stack.

Where I am making mistake? How it can be implemented to work my Back button again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to use `popToViewController` or something.

Use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method for coming back to the home view.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need

```
UINavigationController *navigationControllerNew = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ProfilePage];
```

this should work

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:ProfilePage animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
[self presentModalViewController:ProfilePage animated:YES]
```